# How to install and configure Yate Server?

Tags: installation, server

I am trying on a website to install and configure the Yate Server, but the program does not seem to work. Please give me the steps or lines to enter in the terminal.
I am on 11.10.

Comment: thank you ,but Iam trying this line in terminal after write yate -vvvv the screen of terminal stopped and not give me  (.......@ubuntu:~$ ) to continue ,please help me ...

Answer (score 0):

To install **Yate** type the following in terminal

```
apt-get install yate php5-cli
```

The easiest way to run Yate and debug, during setup is:

```
yate -vvvv
```

If you want the learn more [click here](http://yate.null.ro/pmwiki/index.php?n=Main.GettingStartedOnUbuntu)